# How do you convert array of byte to array of float64

Tags: go

I am searching to convert an array of byte ([]byte) to array of float64 ([]float64) but I didn't have any clues to do it.

I read data from rtlsdr package (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jpoirier/gortlsdr) and would pass it to Pwelch algorithm (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/spectral)

Is it possible to convert large array of byte to float64 ?

(+ another question: did you think that possible to convert Pwelch function to work with uint8 ?)

Thank you so much,
pefr

Comment: it could be easy if you add inputs and outputs

Answer (score 1):

`byte`/`uint8` has 8 bits, `float64` has 64. You can convert `[8]byte` to `float64` like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

main()
{
    in := 1.

    // Convert float64 to [8]byte
    var bytes [8]byte
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bytes[:], math.Float64bits(in))

    // Convert [8]byte to float64
    out := math.Float64frombits(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(bytes[:]))

    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

You may want to chose `binary.BigEndian` instead.

Is that what you are looking for? Or do you want to convert an array of `byte` with length 8n to an array of `float64` with length n? Feel free to comment :-)